# Toggle "Add Subscriber to List" Or "Update Subscriber" in Triggered Interaction via SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, triggered-send

In Email Studio, you can create a Triggered Interaction with various options. Especially in the Subscriber section. We have several hundred of TSD's and I am trying to figure out how to toggle them off via the API.

I searched all of the documentation and this specific section seems to only exist in the UI (SF Documentation) but throughout the API documentation there is no mention of it.

does anyone know if that is a possibility or on UI accessible? And what the properties are to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the following 2 properties for [SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsenddefinition.htm).

[image]

Using these you can define if add/update subscribers brought in via this trigger and you can assign the 'list' you want this to affect via the list property as normal.

---

For REST, this is only around [Transactional Messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createSendDefinition.htm) - not Triggered Sends, you will want to look for these properties:

[image]

when creating a send definition.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to these properties on the [SOAP object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsenddefinition.htm)

> AutoAddSubscribers xsd:boolean Indicates whether a triggered send recipient is added to a subscriber list. If set to True, the call automatically adds the email address associated with the triggered send to a specified subscriber list.
>
> AutoUpdateSubscribers  xsd:boolean Indicates if any subscriber information is updated as part of a triggered send. If set to True, the triggered send call updates any applicable subscriber information with information from the send.